# Studying the Continuity of a function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be an open set, let $f : U \times [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Consider the function $$g(x):= \int_a^b f(x,y) \,dy$$
>   with $x \in U$.
>
> i) Prove that $g$ is continuous in $U$.
>
> ii) consider the function $f : [−1, 1] \times  [−1, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
>   $$f (x, y) :=\begin{cases} \frac {|y|−|x|} {y^2}&\text{ if $|x|<|y|$}\\
> 0 &\text{ if $|x|\geq |y|$}
> \end{cases}$$
>   Let $g(y):= \int_{-1}^1 f(x,y) \,dx$ for $y \in [-1,1]$
>   Study the continuity of $g$.

So I am a bit stuck on how to prove the continuity from the basics: i know how to prove that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then $g=\int f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ but i assume because of the different notation and dimension here, i have to prove a different way? In addition, how would i study the continuity?

Comment: use the definition of continuity and what you knows about the integral of Riemann

Answer (score 1):

First note that continuity is a **local property**. You can exploit this property together with the assumption that $U$ is open in $\Bbb R ^n$. That is: we can simplify the exercise to show that $g$ is continuous in any **compact** subset of $U$ because any point on an open set of $\Bbb R ^n$ (assuming that $\Bbb R ^n$ is a normed space) have a compact neighborhood.

Using compact sets is easy because compacts sets behaves, in many ways, as if there were finite sets. In particular we will use the property that any continuous function in a compact set is **uniformly continuous**, that is, if $C\subset U$ is compact then $f$ is uniformly continuous in $C\times [a,b]$, because Cartesian product of compact sets is a compact set in the product topology.

First note that
$$
\begin{align*}
|g(x_0)-g(x)|&\leqslant \int_{a}^b|f(x_0,y)-f(x,y)|\,\mathrm d y\\
&\leqslant (b-a)\sup_{y\in[a,b]}|f(x_0,y)-f(x,y)|
\end{align*}\tag1
$$
Because $f$ is uniformly continuous in $C\times[a,b]$ then for any $\epsilon >0$ there is a $\delta >0$ such that if $\|(x_0,y_0)-(x,y)\|<\delta $ then $|f(x_0,y_0)-f(x,y)|<\epsilon $ for all $(x_0,y_0),(x,y)\in C\times [a,b]$, where $\|{\cdot}\|$ is any norm on $\Bbb R ^n$ (all norms are equivalent in finite dimensional vector spaces, so you can choose the norm you like more, by example the maximum norm).

Then from $\rm (1)$ we have that if $\|(x_0,y)-(x,y)\|_\infty=|x_0-x|<\delta $ then $|g(x_0)-g(x)|<(b-a)\epsilon $, for all $x_0,x\in C$, what finishes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \in U$ such that  $x_n \to x$

Then $x_n$ is bounded,thus exists a closed ball $B:=\overline{B(0,M)}$ such that $x_n \in B,\forall n \in \Bbb{N}$

Take $f_n(y)=f(x_n,y)$ we have that $f(x,y)$ on $[a,b]$ by continuity of $f$ on  $B \times [a,b]$

In this cartesian product we have the metric $d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))=\sqrt{||x_1-x_2||_2^2+|y_1-y_2|^2}$ where $||x_1-x_2||_2$ is the usual metric on $\Bbb{R}^N$

Since $B\times [a,b]$ is compact then $f$ is uniformly continuous with respect to this metric on $B \times [a,b]$

Let $\epsilon>0$

$\delta>0$ and $n_0 \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $||x_n-x||_2<\delta,\forall n \geq n_0$

So $d((x_n,y),(x,y))=||x_n-x||_2<\delta$ for every $y \in [a,b]$ and $\forall n \geq n_0$

and $|f(x_n,y)-g(x,y)| <\epsilon,\forall y \in [a,b]$ by uniform continuity.

Thus $\sup_{y \in [a,b]}|f(x_n,y)-f(x,y)| \leq \epsilon,  \forall n \geq n_0$

Thus $f_n(y) \to f(x,y)$ uniformply on $[a,b]$

So by using this  and the interchange of limit and riemman integral under uniform convergence,you have the desired conclusion.

For the second part,just study and calculate the integral  use the first part.

Comment: what does it mean to study specifically? can you briefly elaborate or outline on the things i need to show? thanks

Comment: @jamesblack just complute the integral..to find g(x)